# Twilio Say when putting conference on hold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am able to put the conference call on hold, but I would like Twilio to say something like 'This call has been put on hold' to all participants before the music starts playing.

I've been trying to do something like this, but it's not working:

```
response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|

  # Loop over participants and print out a property for each one
  @client.account.conferences.get(@conference_sid).participants.list.each do |participant|
    participant.update(:hold => false) if !params[:hold]
    if params[:hold]
      participant.update(:hold => true)
      r.Say 'This call has been put on hold.'
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Ruby developer but I'm a [twilio](/questions/tagged/twilio) expert.

Besides the `Hold` attribute, you should update the `HoldUrl` attribute to

- **Say** that the call is being put on hold
- **Redirect** to the default Twilio Hold Music (or create your own file)

The `HoldUrl` twiml will look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>This call has been put on hold</Say>
    <Redirect>http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Reference : [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#optional-parameters)

> The 'HoldUrl' attribute lets you specify a URL for music that plays
>   when a participant is held. The URL may be an MP3, a WAV or a TwiML
>   document that uses **Play**, **Say** or **Redirect**.

Comment: trying that out and getting this error: `Twilio::REST::RequestError (HoldUrl is not a valid URL: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Say>This call has been put on hold.</Say><Redirect>http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical</Redirect></Response>):`

Comment: @FutoRicky No, the `HoldUrl` attribute value is an URL (that you host, example : `http://youdomain/onhold`) that returns the `Twiml` snippet I provided you.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks for your help!